# Cypress picks up the wrong element?

Tags: cypress

I am trying to find and click this element using Cypress:

```
<input class="form-control btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Log out">
```

I have tried several variations, but the closest is this:

```
 cy.get("input[type='button']").filter('.btn-primary').should('have.value','Log out').click()
```

So when I run this, I get the following response:

```
expected [ <input.form-control.btn.btn-primary>, 1 more... ] to have value Log out, but the value was Edit.
```

Sure, there is a button there called Edit, but it is not the one I want. I have specified what I want with the `should('have.value','Log out')` clause.

So - why does it insist on trying to use the wrong element & failing?

Update: I finally got this working.

This is the solution I went with in the end:

```
cy.get("input[type='button']").filter('.btn-primary').eq(1)
    .should('have.value','Log out').then(($btn) => {
          $btn.click()
        })
```

Comment: Did you have any luck with my answer?

Comment: @Maccurt - have updated the question with the solution that worked.

Comment: You should make that an answer below. You can answer your own questions. I wonder now if my answer works. I will check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution that worked for me:

```
cy.get("input[type='button']").filter('.btn-primary').eq(1)
.should('have.value','Log out').then(($btn) => {
      $btn.click()
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

can you try

```
cy.get('input').find("[value='Log out']").click()
```

or

```
   cy.get("[value='Log out']").click()
```

Obviously you need your developers to add ids, but I know your situation.

You could also try if there is only one btn-primary

```
cy.get('.btn-primary').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about to set an unique testID for that button and get it as simple as it can be.

Something like:

```
data-test-id= "log-out-button" //put that in your button code
```

and then in Cypress:

```
cy.get('[data-test-id="log-out-button"]')
  .click()
```

even though you can set a function to get those testID's more effectively:

```
Command.Cypress.add('getTestID', (testID) => {
    cy.get(`[data-test-id="${testId}"]`)
})
```

and now everything you do for getting that button (or every element with testID is: `cy.getTestID('log-out-button')`

Comment: I have no control over development. I already have a solution.